# Как через jq изменять параметр в зависимости от ширины экрана

Tags: javascript

Есть код в нём нужно изменять количество слайдов в зависимости от расширения экрана, мой код срабатывает только при перезагрузке страницы. Как сделать чтобы он реагировал на изменения постоянно?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (screen.width < 800) {
    var sl=2;
  }
  else {
    var sl=3;
  }
  $('.your-class').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: sl,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У slick-слайдера есть параметр responsive - в нём с помощью breakpoints можно задавать разное отображение для разных размеров экрана:

```
$('.your-class').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 6,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1199,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 5,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 991,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 767,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Куда этот код нужно добавить? И ещё вопрос есть такой вид слайдера где крайний правый элемент и крайний левый на половину скрыт, но этом же слайдере есть большое фото над ними, как можно убрать это большое фото, но оставить скрытие на половину элементов, вот скриншот https://ibb.co/g3wsVp6

Comment: @Alexander, куда добавить - обновил ответ. А насчёт всех остальных Ваших вопросов по слик-слайдеру - очень рекомендую заглянуть в официальную документацию: там много примеров, как это всё работает (с наглядными картинками) http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: вместо sl нужно использовать любое число?

Comment: @Alexander, ну да - сколько нужно слайдов для показа. Брейкпоинты тоже могут быть любыми - я просто для примера проставил такие

Comment: Спасибо, а со вторым вопросом не получилось, не прокручивается слайдер

Comment: @Alexander, задайте отдельный вопрос по второй проблеме - только обязательно код приложите (html+css+js): в идеале сделайте воспроизводимый пример (скрипты и стили можно подключить через CDN)

Comment: Просмотрите мой новый вопрос пожалуйста